# iOS Sort CFArrayRef of Groups ABRecordRef

Tags: ios, xcode, sorting

I need to sort a CFArrayRef containing ABRecordRef of the contact groups.

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
CFArrayRef allGroups = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllGroups(addressBook);
CFIndex allGroupsCount = ABAddressBookGetGroupCount(addressBook);
```

I know it's easy to do this when sorting the contacts because of ABPersonComparePeopleByName, but the groups doesn't have something like it.
So I don't know how I would use CFArraySortValues in this case.

Tried converting to CFMutable array and then sorting like this:

```
CFMutableArrayRef marray = CFArrayCreateMutableCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, allGroupsCount, allGroups);
CFArraySortValues(marray, CFRangeMake(0, allGroupsCount), (CFComparatorFunction)CFStringCompare, Null);
```

But of course it won't work because it tries to compare strings when receiving ABRecordRef

Appreciate any help

Comment: did you find solution?

Comment: No, havent had much time to work on it.

Answer (score 0):

The way it worked:

```
NSArray *convertedAllGroupsArray = (__bridge NSArray*)allGroups;

id sortGroupName = ^(ABRecordRef * obj1, ABRecordRef * obj2){
    return [[(NSString *) ABRecordCopyValue(obj1, kABGroupNameProperty) lowercaseString] compare:[(NSString *) ABRecordCopyValue(obj2, kABGroupNameProperty) lowercaseString]];
};

NSArray *allGroupsSorted = [convertedAllGroupsArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:sortGroupName];
```

The reason for the conversion from the CFArrayRef to NSArray is to avoid a warning.